# How to compare columns in different excel sheets

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Compare 3 columns in excel sheet 1 with the 3 columns in excel sheet 2 and the same values return a result of column 4 of excel sheet 1 in a column of excel sheet 2

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to make a new column (E) in each sheet that concatenates the other 3:

```
=A1 & B1 & C1
```

This combines all three items into one column.  You can then VLOOKUP this value in the corresponding concatenated column in the other sheet, and return the value in the column 4 that you want..

Give a few more details about your setup and what you've tried so far, and we may be able to provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this sounds like a simple IF statement to compare the columns in sheets 1 and 2

you would essentially put the following code (you must convert the pseudocode  to a "real" formula yourself) in column 4 on sheet two:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A1 = A1, Sheet1!A2 = A2, Sheet1!A3 = A3), ResultIfTrue, ResultIfFalse)
```

This does it without concatenation of cricketbird's solution.